# IOS Fb wall post method not working

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, facebook-graph-api, ios5

I am using following code. It takes me to FB Dialog box where I authorize the app and after authorizing app it takes me back to my applicaiton. However It NEVER post anything on the wall.

Any ideas what is wrong?

```
- (void) login 
{
   AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    appDelegate.facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"MY_APP_ID" andDelegate:self];


    NSArray* permissions =  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream", nil];

    [appDelegate.facebook authorize:permissions];


    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @".", @"name",
                                   @".", @"caption",
                                   nil];

    /*
     NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
     @".", @"name",
     @"Build great social apps and get more installs.", @"caption",
     @"The Facebook SDK for iOS makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated iOS apps.", @"description",
     @"https://developers.facebook.com/ios", @"link",
     @"https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png", @"picture",
     nil];
     */

    // Invoke the dialog
    [appDelegate.facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it like this:

```
graphPath = @"me/feed";
[params setObject:@"link" forKey:@"type"];
[params setObject:pict forKey:@"picture"];
[params setObject:self.url forKey:@"link"];
[params setObject:self.message forKey:@"message"];
[params setObject:self.urlName forKey:@"name"];
[params setObject:self.caption forKey:@"caption"];
[params setObject:self.urlDescription forKey:@"description"];
[appDelegate.facebook requestWithGraphPath:graphPath andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: are you joking? Don't you see that I'm calling `requestWithGraphPath:graphPath andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self]` method? This is the method which actually makes a post on your wall